# What are the drawbacks of running a Python script with `daemonize` vs explicitly writing it to be a daemon with the standard daemon process library?

Tags: python, linux, daemon, python-daemon

I have a Python app which needs to run in the background on one and only one type of system (my own embedded Linux product). I was wondering, if I don't need the Python app to be portable at all, are there any advantages to rewriting it to be a "proper" daemon (with Python's standard daemon process library - [PEP3143](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143)) rather than just launching it with [`daemonize`](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue or not, but if you want the daemon to restart itself via `os.execv` then you may be better off with the daemonization in the code itself.... haven't really thought this through.

Comment: With `daemonize` I've got the thing starting at boot with `init.d` and being kept alive with `monit`. I don't anticipate a scenario where I need it to restart itself any other way than just dying and letting it be resurrected by `monit`.

Comment: I think that `daemonize` would work fine. There are also linux-only daemonizing examples out there that don't use the extra module, but not needed IMHO.